# how to sort attribute in xsl

Tags: xslt, sorting, merge

the following it the input ,I want to merge and sort the elements without using xsl:sort!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE lists SYSTEM "number.dtd">
<numbers>
  <number>
    <num val="7"/>
    <num val="2"/>
    <num val="9"/>
    <num val="16"/>
    <num val="12"/>
    <num val="15"/>
  <number/>
  <number>
    <num val="29"/>
    <num val="18"/>
    <num val="30"/>
    <num val="32"/>
  </number>
</numbers>
```

the out put should be::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE lists SYSTEM "number.dtd">
<numbers>
  <number>
    <num val="2"/>
    <num val="7"/>
    <num val="9"/>
    <num val="12"/>
    <num val="15"/>
    <num val="16"/>
    <num val="18"/>
    <num val="29"/>
    <num val="30"/>
    <num val="32"/>
  </number>
</numbers>
```

in the xsl ,please do not use xsl:sort...  ∩_∩

Comment: @ZAWD: From where we should take the `9`? Also, it's not clear why you don't want a standard XSLT answer using the instruction wich was made for this...

Comment: @Alejandro:Yeah ,it is my mistake ,I have changed it now.Becouse I want to find a new way to solve it.

Comment: @ZAWD: If you don't want to use `xsl:sort` you must implement a sorting algorithm. What sorting algorithm do you want? If you don't know you should start learning about this first.

Comment: @ZAWD Can you explain why `xsl:sort` is not acceptable? I don't understand why you want to avoid using it, if it will achieve what you need.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: En ,I have finished it with xsl:sort,and now I want to find a new way to do it,maybe using a sorting algorithm,which I do not know.

Comment: Your doctype should match your root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using xsl:sort, you could do something like the following, but if your numbers are much higher, negative, non-whole, or not actually numbers, then you will either have to adjust things, or it may just not work (I tried bumping up the last value from 32 to 3200 and xsltproc not only required I give a higher --maxdepth value but also took 52x as long!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <numbers>
      <number>
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate.over.nums">
          <xsl:with-param name="i">0</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </number>
    </numbers>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="iterate.over.nums">
    <xsl:param name="i">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(numbers/number/num/@val &gt;= $i)" />
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number/num[@val = $i]">
          <num val="{@val}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate.over.nums">
          <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```